# Difference between /env/reset and /refresh

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

For example I have a Config Server that just updated some property. Should I run `/env/reset` or `/refresh`
on a client or both?

Functionalities seem to be overlapping according to Spring docs.

> POST to /env to update the Environment and rebind
>   @ConfigurationProperties and log levels
>
> /refresh for re-loading the boot strap context and refreshing the
>   @RefreshScope beans

What if I have `@RefreshScope` and `@ConfigurationProperties` is it a bad design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code:

- **/env/reset** will reset environment properties that were set through
  POST request to /env.
- **/refresh** will pull new properties from the config server and rebind
  them with @RefreshScope beans.

In Spring Boot 1.5.13